# What is the mathematical reasoning behind the methods used in this function that yields the desired results?

Tags: javascript, function, math, combinations, bitwise-operators

I have a function that generates all combinations of a giving string; not including permutations. I believe that i fully understand the logic behind how a given string is passed through the function yielding the desired results. What i am looking to understand is the mathematical reasoning behind the main methods by which the function processes the elements of the string into an array that includes all possible combinations.

Here is the heavily commented code which displays my current understanding of the logical processing of the function.

```
function generateAllCombinationsOfString (str1) { //let str1 = "dog"
    // convert str1 into an array
    var array1 = []; // create var in order to capture elements of str1 into an array
        for (var x = 0, y = 1; x < str1.length; x++,y++) {
            array1[x] = str1.substring(x, y); // we will add each character to array1, in order, starting with the first then ending the loop once the last character has been included in array1
            // for each iteration: x = 0, y = 1     x < str1.length     x++, y++        array1[x] = str1.substring(x, y)
            // iteration 1:      x = 0, y = 1         yes                1    2         array1[0] = str1.substring(0, 1) = "d"
            // iteration 2:      x = 1, y = 2       yes                2    3         array1[1] = str1.substring(1, 2) = "o"
            // iteration 3:      x = 2, y = 3       yes                3    4         array1[2] = str1.substring(2, 3) = "g"
            // iteration 4:      x = 3, y = 4       no
            // end of loop
        }
    // create array containing all combinations of str1
    var combi = []; // create var to capture each possible combination within an array
    var temp = "";  // create cache to temporarily hold elements each possible combination before adding to an array
    var slent = Math.pow(2, array1.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < slent; i++){
            temp = "";
            // for each iteration:      i = 0       i < slent       i++     var combi = []; temp = ""; var slent = Math.pow(2, array1.length)
            // iteration 1:             i = 0         yes            1      var combi = []; temp = ""; var slent = Math.pow(2, 3) = 8
            // iteration 2:             i = 1         yes            2      var combi = [d]; temp = ""; var slent = Math.pow(2, 3) = 8
            // iteration 3:             i = 2         yes            3      var combi = [d, o]; temp = ""; var slent = Math.pow(2, 3) = 8
            // iteration 4:             i = 3         yes            4      var combi = [d, o, do]; temp = ""; var slent = Math.pow(2, 3) = 8
            // iteration 5:             i = 4         yes            5      var combi = [d, o, do, g]; temp = ""; var slent = Math.pow(2, 3) = 8
            // iteration 6:             i = 5         yes            6      var combi = [d, o, do, g, dg]; temp = ""; var slent = Math.pow(2, 3) = 8
            // iteration 7:             i = 6         yes            7      var combi = [d, o, do, g, dg, og]; temp = ""; var slent = Math.pow(2, 3) = 8
            // iteration 8:             i = 7         yes            8      var combi = [d, o, do, g, dg, og, dog]; temp = ""; var slent = Math.pow(2, 3) = 8
            // iteration 9:             i = 8         no
            // end of loop
            for (var j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {
                if ((i & Math.pow(2, j))) {
                    temp += array1[j];
                    // for each iteration:      j = 0       j < array1.length       j++     if((i & Math.pow(2, j)))?                             {temp += array1[j]}
                    // iteration 1-1:           j = 0         yes                    1      if((0 & Math.pow(2, 0)))? => if((0 & 1))? // false
                    // iteration 1-2:           j = 1         yes                    2      if((0 & Math.pow(2, 1)))? => if((0 & 2))? // false
                    // iteration 1-3:           j = 2         yes                    3      if((0 & Math.pow(2, 2)))? => if((0 & 4))? // false
                    // iteration 1-4:           j = 3         no
                    // end of loop
                    // iteration 2-1:           j = 0         yes                    1      if((1 & Math.pow(2, 0)))? => if((1 & 1))? // true  // {temp += array1[0]} => temp = "d"}
                    // iteration 2-2:           j = 1         yes                    2      if((1 & Math.pow(2, 1)))? => if((1 & 2))? // false
                    // iteration 2-3:           j = 2         yes                    3      if((1 & Math.pow(2, 2)))? => if((1 & 4))? // false
                    // iteration 2-4:           j = 3         no
                    // end of loop
                    // iteration 3-1:           j = 0         yes                    1      if((2 & Math.pow(2, 0)))? => if((2 & 1))? // false
                    // iteration 3-2:           j = 1         yes                    2      if((2 & Math.pow(2, 1)))? => if((2 & 2))? // true  // {temp += array1[1] => temp = "o"}
                    // iteration 3-3:           j = 2         yes                    3      if((2 & Math.pow(2, 2)))? => if((2 & 4))? // false
                    // iteration 3-4:           j = 3         no
                    // end of loop
                    // iteration 4-1:           j = 0         yes                    1      if((3 & Math.pow(2, 0)))? => if((3 & 1))? // true  // {temp += array1[0] => temp = "d"}
                    // iteration 4-2:           j = 1         yes                    2      if((3 & Math.pow(2, 1)))? => if((3 & 2))? // true  // {temp += array1[1] => temp = "do"}
                    // iteration 4-3:           j = 2         yes                    3      if((3 & Math.pow(2, 2)))? => if((3 & 4))? // false //
                    // iteration 4-4:           j = 3         no
                    // end of loop
                    // iteration 5-1:           j = 0         yes                    1      if((4 & Math.pow(2, 0)))? => if((4 & 1))? // false //
                    // iteration 5-2:           j = 1         yes                    2      if((4 & Math.pow(2, 1)))? => if((4 & 2))? // false //
                    // iteration 5-3:           j = 2         yes                    3      if((4 & Math.pow(2, 2)))? => if((4 & 4))? // true  // {temp += array1[2] => temp = "g"}
                    // iteration 5-4:           j = 3         no
                    // end of loop
                    // iteration 6-1:           j = 0         yes                    1      if((5 & Math.pow(2, 0)))? => if((5 & 1))? // true  // {temp += array1[0] => temp = "d"}
                    // iteration 6-2:           j = 1         yes                    2      if((5 & Math.pow(2, 1)))? => if((5 & 2))? // false //
                    // iteration 6-3:           j = 2         yes                    3      if((5 & Math.pow(2, 2)))? => if((5 & 4))? // true  // {temp += array1[2] => temp = "dg"}
                    // iteration 6-4:           j = 3         no
                    // end of loop
                    // iteration 7-1:           j = 0         yes                    1      if((6 & Math.pow(2, 0)))? => if((6 & 1))? // false // 
                    // iteration 7-2:           j = 1         yes                    2      if((6 & Math.pow(2, 1)))? => if((6 & 2))? // true  // {temp += array1[1] => temp = "o"}
                    // iteration 7-3:           j = 2         yes                    3      if((6 & Math.pow(2, 2)))? => if((6 & 4))? // true  // {temp += array1[2] => temp = "og"}
                    // iteration 7-4:           j = 3         no         
                    // end of loop
                    // iteration 8-1:           j = 0         yes                    1      if((7 & Math.pow(2, 0)))? => if((7 & 1))? // true  // temp += array1[0] => temp = "d"}
                    // iteration 8-2:           j = 1         yes                    2      if((7 & Math.pow(2, 1)))? => if((7 & 2))? // true  // temp += array1[1] => temp = "do"}
                    // iteration 8-3:           j = 2         yes                    3      if((7 & Math.pow(2, 2)))? => if((7 & 4))? // true  // temp += array1[2] => temp = "dog"}
                    // iteration 8-4:           j = 3         no 
                    // end of loop
                }
            }
            if (temp !== "") { // if var temp is not an empty string then we add elements of var temp to end of the array var combi at the end of each loop cycle
                combi.push(temp); 
                // for each iteration       if(temp !== "")?
                // iteration 1:             if(temp !== "")? // false //
                // iteration 2:             if(temp !== "")? // true // combi.push(temp) => combi.push("d") 
                // iteration 3:             if(temp !== "")? // true // combi.push(temp) => combi.push("o") 
                // iteration 4:             if(temp !== "")? // true // combi.push(temp) => combi.push("do")
                // iteration 5:             if(temp !== "")? // true // combi.push(temp) => combi.push("g")
                // iteration 6:             if(temp !== "")? // true // combi.push(temp) => combi.push("dg")
                // iteration 7:             if(temp !== "")? // true // combi.push(temp) => combi.push("og")
                // iteration 8:             if(temp !== "")? // true // combi.push(temp) => combi.push("dog")
            }
        }
        // join array of combinations while seperating each by a new line
        console.log(combi.join("\n"))
        /*  expected output if str1 = "dog"

            d
            o
            do
            g
            dg
            og
            dog

        */
}
```

Below is the section that includes the pieces that i would like to further understand the reasoning behind.

```
    var combi = [];
    var temp = "";  
    var slent = Math.pow(2, array1.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < slent; i++){
            temp = "";

            for (var j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {
                if ((i & Math.pow(2, j))) {
                    temp += array1[j];
                }
            }
            if (temp !== "") { 
                combi.push(temp); 
            }
        }
```

How is it that the variable "slent" with the above definition gives us the exact condition at which the entire loop stops at the right moment after the last possible combinations has been added to the var combi?

furthermore, the second FOR loop in that section also contains a similar condition that works along with the initial expression of j= 0 as well as the condition contained in the IF statement that seems to perfectly process and push each possible combination into the variable "combi" while keeping from adding incorrect elements into each iteration. How is it that the Math.pow() methods used in this function yield the desired results?

What is the reasoning behind the key-points mentioned above? I feel that i fully understand "how" the function works, but i would like to know "why" is the method working. How does one know that these methods together will allow the function to return what is desired?

I feel like it has everything to do with the mathematical definition of combinations but i am not familiar with this specific topic so i am wondering if anyone can enlighten me if i have structured this question in a way that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, with n distinct characters taken in order, with some taken or not, there are 2^n possibilities of character sets (including the empty set, which the routine is careful not to add). These are associated with the possible n-digit base 2 numbers who range from 0 to the 2^n-1. Looping through those number, for each number the code checks the bit associated with each character, and includes the character if the bit is 1 and does not if it is 0.

Comment: Do you know of any resources that may clarify this a bit further? It would be of great use to brush up on this mathematical principle. I appreciate any guidance.

Comment: The basic idea is that 2^n is the number of subsets of an n-element set. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383485/finding-the-number-of-subsets-of-s

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying the concept as well as providing reference. You are a scholar my friend.